# JavaScript: Detect 'Like' click

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-like

I use this code to detect like click:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {

                //to do...

            } 
);
```

and it works well, so what is my problem.
When the user clicks the like button, it should open a pop-up window.
I use a synchronous call that doesn't block pop-up windows.

```
 $("#div1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "./ajax.php",
      async: false,
      data: "POST",
      success:  function() {
        window.open("./ajax.php","_blank"); 

      }
    });
  });
```

This code works great for buttons, custom divs, pictures... but it won't work for like object, i tried to put 'id' property to like object or append like object to custom div and detect custom/outer div click, but it doesn't work.

I can't use this with `FB.Event.subscribe` because it's asynchronously, and pop-up blocker blocks pop-up. 
So I need other way to detect like click.

Comment: You probably can't, unless you hook into the events provided by facebook, as the button is in an iframe from another domain.

Comment: Isn't the like button in an iframe from another domain?  If so, you can't directly intercept events in that iframe unless the FB API provides you access.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem with iFrames and 3rd party content.

One way we might do this is to place a transparent div above the FB element.  Our click handler for this div, when triggered, opens our pop-up. Next, in the same handler, we then trigger a click on the FB element below it.  If you post a fiddle, I can see if this is feasible with your setup.

Comment: @Djomla1989 "Two clicks or one?" - Your choice.  You could make it so that on the first click, only your handler fires, and on the second click the facebook button works.

Answer (score 0):

The like button is in an iFrame, so you can't attach an event handler. But you can add the AJAX call to Facebook's function:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
   function(response) {
     $.ajax({
      url: "./ajax.php",
      async: false,
      data: "POST",
      success:  function() {
        window.open("./ajax.php","_blank"); 
      }
    });
   } 
);
```

Comment: It's asynchronous call so pop-up blocker will block my pop-up window.